# Django - Return empty value from select tag of html

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

There's a form for students to register .
Each of the students are in a school.
And by using forms.ModelChoiceField the name of schools will be shown in the template using a 'select' tag. ( a dropdown list )
**The main problem is, After choosing one 'option' of the 'select' tag , I can't get the select's value in views.py** .

models.py

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class SchoolForm(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.name

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    student_school = SchoolForm(queryset = School.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name', 'school')
```

views.py

```
def student_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentForm(request.POST)
        form.school = request.POST['school']

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save
     else:
         form = StudentForm()

     return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

index.html

```
<form method="post" action={% 'student_register' %}>
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.name }}
    <select id="id_school" name="school">
        {% for name in form.student_school %}
            <option value={{ name }}>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Your field name reads as `student_school`. Should the line in your view be `form.school = request.POST['student_school']` ?

Comment: I don't think so . Because 'student_school' is just for getting objects and send them to the template ( that's not my problem ) . I have given id to the <select> tag manually and I wanna get the data from select tag in views.py.

Comment: Does the dropdown list itself render correctly? Do you see the correct school names in the list?

Comment: Yes there's no problem with rendering the student_school and show it in a <select> tag